# Google ID Token as Authorization Token?

Tags: authentication, authorization, token

I really don't get it why a Google ID Token shouldn't be used as my access token as well.
Imagine a scenario where I have an app where people can create advertisements and other can contact them.

Why would it be important to have this second layer of creating an access token and using that one instead of the id token directly? If all users are allowed to use all rest routes?
Just because more information is inside the ID token than in the access token?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Google ID Token as an access token in scenarios where users are allowed to create advertisements and contact each other is not recommended for several reasons:

1. **Scope and Authorization**: Access tokens and ID tokens serve different purposes. Access tokens are typically used to grant access to specific resources or perform specific actions on behalf of a user. They are associated with a set of permissions (scopes) that define what actions the token bearer can perform. In contrast, ID tokens are primarily used for authentication, verifying the identity of the user. Using an ID token as an access token might not carry the necessary scopes or permissions required to perform actions like creating advertisements or contacting other users.
2. **Security**: Access tokens and ID tokens have different security characteristics. Access tokens are short-lived and designed to be used by the client to access protected resources on the server. They should be kept confidential and not exposed to the client-side code or users. ID tokens, on the other hand, are intended to be consumed by the client-side code to authenticate the user and provide personalized experiences. Exposing an ID token to the client-side code or using it as an access token could expose sensitive user information, potentially leading to security risks.
3. **User Privacy**: ID tokens often contain sensitive user information, such as email addresses, profile information, and potentially other personal data. Using an ID token as an access token exposes this information to the client-side code, which may not have a legitimate need for it. This could violate user privacy and data protection regulations.
4. **Future Compatibility**: ID tokens are subject to change as identity and authentication protocols evolve. Relying on an ID token as an access token might not be future-proof, as changes to authentication mechanisms could affect the format or contents of ID tokens, potentially breaking existing functionality.

In summary, while it might seem convenient to use an ID token as an access token in certain scenarios, it is not recommended due to differences in purpose, security implications, user privacy concerns, and potential compatibility issues. It's best practice to use access tokens specifically designed for authorization purposes and to carefully manage the scopes and permissions associated with them.

Comment: Sorry, this is not helpful and only generic information about those token types. Since everyone can register my app using his/her google account, everyone with an ID token can also retrieve an access token. Why would it be more safe to have the access token as my second layer. I still don't see a concrete example why this is not good for my specific use case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).